# What is the way to specify download directory while using download missing resources in command line?

Tags: python, anaconda, nltk

I am trying to use nltk for lexical parsing. As part of this, whenever I try to run things like stopwords or wordnet, I get "Resource not found" error. In Anaconda, I am able to see the recommended steps to be taken such as:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('wordnet')
```

But, this installs the resources under my home directory. I would expect it to be downloaded under the anaconda nltk library. Is there a conda command to update the nltk package to download wordnet or resources found missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the answer to this issue. Thought of posting it so that it is useful to others.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('wordnet', download_dir='/users/droy/anaconda/nltk/wordnet')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add this (installed) directory that is within your home directory to PYTHONPATH variable, for it to work.